# Webpack cant resolve and point to my node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, three.js, webpack-dev-server

I have problems running the Three.js library as a module according to the manual
https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Import-via-modules

This is what I have done:

**Create package.json**

```
npm init
```

**Install webpack**

```
npm i --save-dev webpack webpack-cli
```

**Install Three.js**

```
npm install three
```

**Create index.html with following code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>three.js webgl - cloth simulation</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #cce0ff;
            color: #000;
        }

        a {
            color: #080;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="module" src="./src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Create a src folder and putting a file named index.js in src folder where I import three**

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

**Installing liveserver for running a server:**

```
npm install live-server -g
```

**Running the server:**

```
live-server
```

**This gives me the error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three".
>   Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

**It works however with this syntax providing the full path:**

```
import * as THREE from '../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
```

How come webpack doesnt resolve the path to my node_modules?

I have also tried creating a **webpack.config.js** file:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        modules: ['./node_modules']
    }
};
```

But with the same result:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three".
>   Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Any hint is very much apreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I tried with Babel for handling ES6:

**Install:**

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env 
npm install --save-dev babel-loader
```

**Edited y webpack.config.js according to this:**
https://createapp.dev/webpack

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Added .babelrc with:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

But still no success

Comment: Try instead `const THREE = require('three')` if this is a node project than node isn't hip to es6 import statements due to there being no JavaScript engine yet that natively supports ES6 modules

Comment: What @william said. You'll need to install @babel/core and babel-loader, then configure babel-loader in webpack.config.json. And you'll likely want to create a .babelrc if you want to use es6.

Comment: Thanks however `const THREE = require('three')` gives me the errormessage: *index.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined* ... I tried to install babel with: `npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env` and `npm install --save-dev babel-loader` but that didnt work either. Same errormessage as before: *Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*

Comment: See my update above

Answer (score 5):

You **can** use three.js with ES6 modules and npm in-browser, without webpack or any other bundle, by doing this:

```
npm install three
```

And open an HTML page, and link to a `type="module"` script:

```
  <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
```

in `main.js` you must write, in this format:

```
import * as THREE from './node_modules/three/src/Three.js';
```

And this will work. Note the import statement has to take that form, pointing at the file, with the `./` and `.js`.

Comment: Why isn't it a simple as `import * as THREE from 'three';`??

Comment: That doesn't work - the path is now ./node_modules/three/build/Three.js. But that doesn't work either...throws a MIME type error.

Answer (score 0):

I also counter this error.

I just want a simple `import * as THREE from 'three'` like this.

I use a bundler webpack

this is my simple configuration

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode:'development',  
  entry: './src/main.js',
  watch: true,
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
};
```

and in my index.html I put the path of dist in my script tag.

```
 <script type="module" src="../dist/main.js"></script>
```

and run

```
npm run build
```